# jquery div replace from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two-dimensional array which I get back as JSON from a call.

and I also have a 3-by-3 div.

as follows:

```
<div id="type0">
    <div id="image00"></div>
    <div id="image01"></div>
    <div id="image02"></div>
</div><br />

<div id="type1">
    <div id="image10"></div>
    <div id="image11"></div>
    <div id="image12"></div>
</div><br />

<div id="type2">
    <div id="image20"></div>
    <div id="image21"></div>
    <div id="image22"></div>
</div><br />
```

and i have the loop below to iterate the data.

```
$.each(res, function (i, tickets) {
     $.each(tickets, function (j, ticket) {

         console.log('i:' + i);
         console.log('j:' + j); 



     });
 });
```

How can I replace the content of the div above every time this script is invoked?

Essentially, I want to fill up the 3-by-3 div.

So, with the inner loop, I guess I need something like:

```
$("#type1").$("#image1").html(image here);
```

What's the correct way to do this?

i and j gives u, 0,1,2 and 0,1,2.

or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: One issue that should be corrected is that the value of `ID` must be unique within the HTML document. You have `id="image0"` (and so on) set three times.

Comment: yes, i just realized that. i will edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and [`start with attribute`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$.each(res, function (i, tickets) {
     $.each(tickets, function (j, ticket) {
         $('div[id^=img]').eq(j).text(ticket)
     });
 });
```

---

```
$.each(res, function (i, tickets) {
     var ind = i;
     $.each(tickets, function (j, ticket) {
         $('#image'+ind+j).text(ticket)
     });
 });
```

Comment: how does i adds in here? how can i make `image00` ? you are just doing `j`

Comment: @DarthVader `:))` just what Darth Vador will say `:P` [quote]: "I find your lack of faith disturbing." eh ! :)

Comment: @DarthVader I have updated ma answer, hope that it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ids as selectors since they are unique

```
$.each(res, function (i, tickets) {
     $.each(tickets, function (j, ticket) {
         $(('#image'+i)+j).html(image here)
     });
 });
```